# Multiple conservation of momentum in one

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, conservation-laws

I am in a Grade 12 Physics course and my teacher gave this question for bonus marks, to be solved with only highschool concepts. I suspect that this problem has to do with conservation of momentum, but I am stuck on how to approach it seeing as no numbers are given. I've looked at it for hours but I'm still completely stumped, and pointers would be appreciated!

Consider the following scenario. You are sitting in a cart containing several bags of sand at the top of a hill. The path you want to take goes down the hill and then up the next, which is higher than yours. There is no friction between your cart and the path. To get started, you throw one bag of sand out the back of the cart. In order to make it as far as possible up the other hill, when should you throw the other bags out? All bags have the same mass and you always throw them at the same speed relative to the cart out of the back.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange Physics! Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our [meta site](//meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5958) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

As another hint to your problem, you'll also want to consider conservation of energy (there's a big clue in your problem that conservation of energy is important --there is no friction between the cart and the path).

To start you off, here are the important conservation of energy equations for your problem:

$$E_k = \frac{1}{2}mv^2= \frac{1}{2}\frac{p^2}{m}$$

$$E_g=mgh$$

One thing to keep in mind is that throwing the sand bag increases your total energy, and your final height increases with energy. Another way of framing the problem is, when should you throw the sand bags as to maximize your total energy?

Comment: Same approach, different physical quantity. High-five! :-)

Comment: Wait, but... The action of throwing itself breaks conservation of energy. You are using your body's energy as input to the mechanical system. Like how both the cart and a bag got moving from stasis. Each time you throw a bag you add energy to the mechanical system. Anyway the idea still works, this hole doesn't really break it. You might want to edit to cover this though, after all the OP is trying to learn, so we better not mislead them.

Comment: Well, I do say that throwing the sandbag increases the total energy. It's still possible to apply conservation of energy, you just need to include the energy gained from throwing the bags. I hope my original answer made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of momentum is a little inconvenient under gravity. Anyway, the last sentence in the question means that $p = mv$, throwing each sand bag gives the same momentum boost. Let's name it $\Delta p$. (you might need to work that out since your teacher might ask for a detailed explanation; I'll leave that to you)

Now your question asks, how to maximize your chance of getting over the next, higher hilltop? You can understand the question as "how to maximize the momentum of the cart?", so you'll have to **focus on the processes in which momentum changes**, that is, except $\Delta p$, which is constant and you can't change it. And don't forget the question is about **when to throw bags out**.